# How does Complex Analysis by Bak justify an inequality on page 29 (Thm 2.9)?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z,h$ be complex numbers. They make the following statement.

> Let \begin{align*} b_n := \frac{(z+h)^n-z^n}{h}-nz^{n-1} &=
> \sum_{k=2}^n \binom{n}{k} h^{k-1}z^{n-k}\\ &\leq |h| \sum_{k=0}^n
> \binom{n}{k} |z|^{n-k} \end{align*} Given that $|h|\leq 1$.

The issue here is, the equality on the top line is of complex numbers. They then use a less-than-or-equals to sign to compare this complex value to a real value on the bottom, here.

This seems like nonsense to me, since you can't define inequalities over $\mathbb{C}$ in the way we would need to conduct analysis. Am I missing something? Any explanation would be helpful.

Comment: True, they shuold have inserted absolute value sign throughout.

Comment: Seems like an error. Possibly they meant to consider $|b_n|$.

Comment: Thanks. If anyone has the book, it would be nice for someone to go to that section to verify that I did not misrepresent their work. For reference, this is from the 3rd edition.

Comment: its wrong, as complex number are not linearly ordered, so it cannot be an inequality. It need absolute value bars around the expressions, then it becomes real non-negative numbers, what can be compared

Answer (score 0):

> Let \begin{align*} b_n := \frac{(z+h)^n-z^n}{h}-nz^{n-1} &=
> \sum_{k=2}^n \binom{n}{k} h^{k-1}z^{n-k}\\ &\leq |h| \sum_{k=0}^n
> \binom{n}{k} |z|^{n-k} \end{align*} Given that $|h|\leq 1$.

It isn't clear to me which of the assertions that you are questioning.  In effect, the analysis can be presented as two assertions, which I will justify, one at a time:

- $R = S.$
- $S \leq T$.

---

The first thing to note is that there is an apparent oversight on the part of the author:  the assertions should be changed to (in effect)

- $R = S.$
- $|~S~| \leq T.$

The above two assertions are what I am going to demonstrate, one at a time.

---

$$(z + h)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}h^k ~z^{n-k} \implies $$

$$(z + h)^n - z^n = \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}h^k ~z^{n-k} \implies $$

$$\frac{(z + h)^n - z^n}{h} = \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}h^{k-1} ~z^{n-k} \implies $$

$$\frac{(z + h)^n - z^n}{h} - nz^{n-1} = \sum_{k=2}^n \binom{n}{k}h^{k-1} ~z^{n-k}.$$

---

The second assertion, in the form that I have altered it to, takes a bit of work.  The triangle inequality, applied to Complex Numbers of the form $w_2, w_3, \cdots, w_n$, implies that

$$| ~w_2 + w_3 + \cdots + w_n ~| \leq |w_2| + |w_3| + \cdots + |w_n|.$$

So, you can let $w_k$ represent

$$\binom{n}{k} h^{k-1} ~z^{n-k}.$$

This then implies that

$$\left| ~\sum_{k=2}^n \binom{n}{k} h^{k-1} ~z^{n-k} ~\right| ~\leq~ \sum_{k=2}^n \binom{n}{k} \left| ~h^{k-1} ~z^{n-k} ~\right| \\ = 
\sum_{k=2}^n \binom{n}{k} \left\{ ~\left| ~h^{k-1} ~\right| \times \left| ~z ~\right|^{n-k} ~\right\}.$$

Here, I am making strong use of the fact that given any two Complex numbers $z_1, z_2$ you have that $|~z_1 \times z_2~| = |z_1| \times |z_2|.$

All that remains is to notice that since $|h| \leq 1$, you have that 
$|h| \geq \left| ~h^{k-1} ~\right| ~: ~k \in \{2,3,\cdots,n\}.$